# C - Using loop and function that returns time (similar to a stopwatch)

Tags: c

So, I have been working with a loop and I am trying to make a function where, from the moment the code runs, it will start a counter/stopwatch. While the loop is running, I want to call for the time on the counter/stopwatch multiples times. Also, the stopwatch/counter is never supposed to stop.

So far I tried make this function for the counter.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

struct timeval temp;
void  menu(){
printf("%d \n", gtime());
}

int gtime(){
//clock_t ttime;
gettingmeofday(&temp, NULL);
int ttime = temp.tv_usec;
return ttime;
}
```

Any help is welcome!! :)
Thank you~

Comment: Use `clock_gettime` with `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID`. I don't see any loop in your code.

Comment: Are you not getting an implicit function declaration warning (error)?

Comment: Are you trying to make a timer? If so check out timerfd and select or poll to make your life easier.

Comment: I am getting an error. 
`' Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
gettingmeofday                      /var/tmp//ccqZai4t.o
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status '`

Comment: I didn't add the loop on the post since I was only seeking to understand how to make a counter.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]" to learn how this site works. -- Please [edit] your question and provide the [mre] that leads to the error you mention. Copy it verbatim as text, do not use screenshots.